# Выбор элемента jQuery с фильтром

Tags: html, jquery

Не могу понять как задать селектор, чтоб выбрать нужный мне элемент

К примеру есть html код:

```
<div class="inner">
<div class="a-row" style="position: relative">

<div class="a-row a-size-small s9Brand">Home</div>

<span class="a-color-price a-size-base">$8.99</span>
<div class="a-icon a-icon-img a-icon-small" style="margin-left: 4px"><span class="a-icon-alt">price</span></div>
</div></div>


<div class="inner">
<div class="a-row" style="position: relative">

<div class="a-row a-size-small s9Brand">Home</div>

<span class="a-color-price a-size-base">$8.99</span>
</div></div>
```

Хочу удалить элемент inner и все что внутри него, при этом нужно удалить только тот элемент в котором есть элемент с классом a-icon

Answer (score 1):

Нужно воспользоваться [селектором `has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```js
$('.inner:has(.a-icon)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner">
  <div class="a-row" style="position: relative">

    <div class="a-row a-size-small s9Brand">Home to delete</div>

    <span class="a-color-price a-size-base">$8.99</span>
    <div class="a-icon a-icon-img a-icon-small" style="margin-left: 4px"><span class="a-icon-alt">price</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="inner">
  <div class="a-row" style="position: relative">

    <div class="a-row a-size-small s9Brand">Home should stay</div>

    <span class="a-color-price a-size-base">$8.99</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое заработало, подскажите еще пожалуйста, контент обновляется с помощью ajax(динамически) (не знаю как правильно объяснить), и скрипт  `$('.inner:has(.a-icon)').remove();` срабатывает при первой загрузки страницы, а вот если перейти на другую страницу с контентом, то элементы не удаляются, можно ли как-то обернуть скрипт тоже в динамическое обновление??

Comment: @ПашаПалиенко, добавить вызов в success обработчик запроса

Comment: не силен в jquery, можно пример?

Comment: @ПашаПалиенко, неа, я ж не знаю как и что у тебя вызывается